# Reduce Bigger content in to tiny one using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Expected output: i want some content in the beginning, in images clearly shows appropriate result[image]

what i tried: HTML

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Testing
<ul>
<li>first</li>
</ul>

</div>
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read More</a>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
        $(".show_hide").text(txt);
        $(this).prev('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});

</script>
```

Codepen link:[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Shahbazmak/pen/gOPWwbY)

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one then just separate the header.

```html
<div class="Header">Testing</div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

But if there are multiple items like this, then you can use context of the button which is clicked and then modify around it. Also since you are already using jQuery you can have a look at [Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) for multiple items like this.